# How to create Calendar Table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to create Calendar Table Oracle. like i have table of holidays

```
Id  FromDate    ToDate  Description
1   1-Feb-11    3-Feb-11    Maintance
3   2-Sep-09    5-Sep-09    Eid Holiday Fine Block
4   3-Dec-09    4-Dec-09    Due to System Problem
5   4-Dec-07    04-Dec-07   National Day
```

I want to make `CTE` from this table from minimum `fromdate` and maximum `todate`.

Expecting table like.

```
Date        HolidayName

11-Feb-11   Maintance
12-Feb-11   Maintance
13-Feb-11   Maintance
02-Sep-09   Eid Holiday
03-Sep-09   Eid Holiday
04-Sep-09   Eid Holiday
05-Sep-09   Eid Holiday
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`connect by level` clause may be used :

```
 select FromDate+level-1 "Date", Description "HolidayName"
   from holiday 
connect by level <=  ToDate - FromDate + 1
  group by FromDate+level-1, Description
  order by 1;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/437f8/1)

Answer (score 1):

IN oracle 11g 2 You can use CTE Recursive

like this.

```
WITH CTE(from_date, i, datediff,description) AS
(
  SELECT from_date, 1 AS i, trunc(to_date - from_date) as datediff,description
  FROM t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT from_date, i + 1, datediff,description
  FROM CTE
  WHERE i <= datediff
)
, dates as (select i, from_date + i - 1 as "Date",description from CTE)
SELECT "Date",description "HolidayName"
FROM dates
ORDER BY description desc
```

*Sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac34c/7*